# If for an harmonic function $u$ in $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R_+$, $u(\mathbf{0},y) = 0$ then $u \equiv 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

If $u$ is a harmonic function on $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R_+$ and $$u(\mathbf{0},y) = 0$$ (here $\mathbf{0} \in \mathbb R^n$ and $y \in \mathbb R_+$) and $u$ depends radially on the first variable, then is it true that $u \equiv 0$?

Comment: When you say "$u$ depends radially on the first variable" do you mean $u(x,y) = v( \vert x \vert ,y)$ for $v: \mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$?